# Invariant theory of $SL_2$ over a field of positive characteristic

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characteristic-p, invariant-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$. Let $W$ be a finite dimensional $SL_2$-module over $k$. Let $V$ be the natural representation of $SL_2$.

> What can be said - in general, or for specific examples - about the ring of invariants $R_W:=k[W]^{SL_2}$.

One specific example that I'd like to know about is the case where $W$ is the space $S^d V$ of binary forms of degree $d$, or where $W$ is a direct sum of such spaces.

Let $D_W$ denote the multiset of the degrees of generators for $R_W$ (as an algebra over $k$). Apart from the calculation of $D_W$ and, ideally, explicit generators and relations for the examples from binary forms (for small degrees and specific values of $p$), I'd like to know the answer to general questions such as the following:-

> For what values of $p$ is $D_{S^dV}$ the same as it would be in characteristic zero?

Comment: By power reductivity one knows at least that if $W$ comes from a module over $\Bbb Z$, as in the case of $S^dV$, then every generator of $R_W$ has a power that comes from an invariant in characteristic zero.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen Thanks for your helpful comment. I found  your paper concerning power reductively. I include the reference (http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.0787) here for others who may be interested.